# Extract CSS from Lit tagged templates

Tags: lit, css-in-js

We are in a situation where we have to ship some of the global styles written with Lit tagged templates as plain css files.

Basically converting the following:

```js
// global.ts
import { css, unsafeCSS } from 'lit';
import * as tokens from 'xyz-design-tokens';

export default css`
  h1 {
    font-size: ${unsafeCSS(tokens.h1FontSize)};
  }
`;
```

to

```css
/* global.css */
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

I'v tried to use postcss-cli and [postcss-lit](https://github.com/43081j/postcss-lit) but it just ends up outputting the same content of the `global.ts` file. Is there any way to extract CSS out of the tagged templates and output as css files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "output" part, you might have to use the `fs` module to process your lit files in batch.

To extract (the computed) CSS out of the tagged templates, you can access `cssText`.

```
const tokens = {
  h1Color: "red"
}
const style = css`
  h1 {
    font-size: "16px";
    color: ${unsafeCSS(tokens.h1Color)};
  }
`;
console.log(style.cssText);
```

[image]

For css inside a lit class, you need to create an object from the class. Then you access the it as a property.

```
@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  themeCss = `
    h1 {
      color: ${unsafeCSS(tokens.h1Color)};
    }
  `;
  
  render() {
    
    return html`
        <div>
          <style>${this.themeCss}</style>
          <h1>Hello world</h1>
        </div>
    `;
  }
}
const greet = new SimpleGreeting()
console.log(greet.themeCss);
```

[image]

See this [lit playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gICAgICAgICAgPHN0eWxlPiR7dGhpcy50aGVtZUNzc308L3N0eWxlPlxuICAgICAgICAgIDxoMT5IZWxsbyB3b3JsZDwvaDE-XG4gICAgICAgIDwvZGl2PlxuICAgIGA7XG4gIH1cbn1cbmNvbnN0IGdyZWV0ID0gbmV3IFNpbXBsZUdyZWV0aW5nKClcbmNvbnNvbGUubG9nKGdyZWV0LnRoZW1lQ3NzKTtcbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-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) demo in action

Comment: I dont think this addresses the concern of the OP.

Comment: My bad.. read the question wrongly. I've updated the answer